# Standard error of beta: n-1 or n-2?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, standard-error

My stats book (Gerstman's *Biostatistics for Public Health*) has the following formula for the confidence interval of the slope parameter beta. The formula indicates that the denominator for the SE of beta should use $n-2$. However, the example that immediately follows in the book uses $n-1$ in the denominator of the SE of beta. Is this a mistake? Is there missing info? Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a mistake. The [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#/Confidence_intervals) for $\hat{\beta}$ involves degree of freedom $n-2$, not $n-1$. Note that, the explanation has more typos. In the second bullet-point, it finds $t_{n-2}$, but uses as if it was $t_{n-1}$ in the third bullet point.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I thought, but was just concerned there was something I was missing. Again, thank you!

Comment: Done. Thanks again!